# R: How to add new element to character without changing the data structure of it?

Tags: r, list, insert

I have the following:

```
print(strategy_reallocations)
                      1       13          17        
A                    "B"     "C"         "D"

print(dimnames(strategy_reallocations))
[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[1] "B"  "C" "D"

print(is.character(strategy_reallocations))
[1] TRUE
```

I want to add another element to this character so that it looks like:

```
                  0       1       13       17      
A                "Z"     "B"     "C"      "D"
```

I could not find the right answer on G. What I have tried so far is,

```
strategy_reallocations <- c("Z", strategy_reallocations)
```

But this breaks the datastructure of character.

```
print(strategy_reallocations)
[1] "Z"      "B"     "C" "D"
```

How can I do this?

EDIT:

```
str(strategy_reallocations)
chr [1, 1:3] "B" "C" "D"
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr "A"
  ..$ : chr [1:3] "1" "13" "17"
```

Comment: I am guessing you have a matrix but we don't actually know. Please add the output of `str(strategy_reallocations)` to the question [also smaller mnemonic variable names are *much* easier to type! :-) ].

Comment: Let's also point out that a better data.structure for this type of data might be a named vector (easy indexing) or a two column data.frame (easy merging).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x <- matrix(c("b", "c", "d"), nrow=1)
colnames(x) <- c(1, 13, 17)
rownames(x) <- "a"

cbind(`0`="z", x)
#  0   1   13  17 
#a "z" "b" "c" "d"
```

The backticks are necessary, because `0` is not a valid variable name.